# How to use jxls excel fuction with ternary operator

Tags: jxls

this is my jxls code :

```
<jx:forEach var="data" items="${dataList}">

  ${data.TEST_COL18 != null ? [S3/M3*100] : ""} 

</jx:forEach>
```

I think it is right, but it returns strange String like this `'[l@5c6f3524'`

How can I solve this problem?